# Simple select where query runs faster WITHOUT primary key

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables with the same data structure except that **one has a primary key on a column and the other don't**.

The thing is, query on the table **with primary key run in average 6x to 10x slower** than the one without primary key..

**Table without PK**

```
CREATE TABLE `ULRCON01` 
(
`CONSTAC`   VARCHAR ( 7 ) NOT NULL,
`DATCRED`   VARCHAR ( 8 ),
`DATMAJD`   VARCHAR ( 8 ),
`MONTANM`   DECIMAL ( 19 ),
`CONSTLC`   VARCHAR ( 10 ),
`CONSTLL`   VARCHAR ( 35 ),
);
```

**Table with PK**

```
CREATE TABLE `ULRCON01` 
(
`CONSTAC`   VARCHAR ( 7 ) NOT NULL,
`DATCRED`   VARCHAR ( 8 ),
`DATMAJD`   VARCHAR ( 8 ),
`MONTANM`   DECIMAL ( 19 ),
`CONSTLC`   VARCHAR ( 10 ),
`CONSTLL`   VARCHAR ( 35 ),
PRIMARY KEY(`CONSTAC`)
);
```

**The query**

```
SELECT CONSTLC FROM ULRCON01 WHERE CONSTAC LIKE 'SIRCA00'
```

**And the results..**

```
// PK on CONSTAC
Request "SELECT CONSTLC FROM ULRCON01 WHERE CONSTAC LIKE 'SIRCA00'" executed in 10ms

// No PK
Request "SELECT CONSTLC FROM ULRCON01 WHERE CONSTAC LIKE 'SIRCA00'" executed in 1ms
```

I just don't understand.. Why would primary key slow down a simple select where query.. Any ideas ?

Comment: That data are probably cached for the second run.  Have you tried reversing the order?

Comment: The two queries are not runned in the same instance. I do the first one, then exit, change the table, re-build and run the same test :/

Comment: Have you tried using `=` instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: After fixing the syntax error in the first table definition, the select query compiles to the same sequence of bytecode instructions for the two table definitions, so they should be running in about the same time. I suspect the problem lies in something you're not showing or mentioning.

Comment: Also, since you're using varchar and decimal in your table definitions, you should read this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I can confirm (based on the output of the `EXPLAIN` command) that the two queries have identical bytecode.  There must be something you're not mentioning.  Do you have any `CREATE INDEX` statements?  Can you provide some sample data from your table?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delay, I've been busy all week end. Yes they are indexes in the db, but not on this table. The thing I don't understand is that I tried to remove everything (all indexes, field's length etc) but only removing PK worked.. And yeah @JohnWu I tried with = for the same results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after more investigation, it cames from the way we are using SQLiteDataReader..
We specified

```
using (var myReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
```

And it's quite costfull (also that's why it runs faster without primary keys..). So now we use

```
using (var myReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
```

Which speed up the request to 2ms instead of 10 !